# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. T-Sql

Tags: t-sql, datetime, converters

I have a varchar column in my database called ref003 which stores datetime like the below

```
2021-04-04 20:01:03
```

Here, date format is like `yyyy-MM-DD`

When I execute the below select query I am getting error

```
SELECT *
FROM FileIndex
WHERE CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(30), CONVERT(DATETIME, Ref003, 105), 101) AS DATE) 
    BETWEEN CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, '01-01-2021', 105), 101) AS DATE) 
    AND CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, '31-12-2021', 105), 101) AS DATE)
```

And the error is

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 Conversion failed when converting
> date and/or time from character string.

What is the problem here and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: *"I have a varchar column in my database callled ref003 which stores datetime like the below"* The *real* question is why are you storing date and time values as a `varchar` in the first place? Fix the design, fix the problem.

Comment: because this is a dynamic column which can store anything but for the current scenario this always store varchar

Comment: As for the error, I don't doubt it's because you have *at least* one row where the value of `Ref003` isn't able to be converted. Though a quick read of [Date and Time Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles) will tell you that the style `105` isn't going to work on the value `'2021-04-04 20:01:03'`.

Comment: *"because this is a dynamic column which can store anything but for the current scenario this always store varchar"* Then you have an even bigger design flaw. EAV tables are never a good idea in an RDBMS. Because of this flaw `CONVERT(DATETIME, Ref003, 105)` is *going* to likely try to convert **every** value of `Ref003` in your table; including those that aren't "date times". This only strengthens my statement: fix the design, fix the problem.

Comment: @TWMTV `this is a dynamic column ` there's no such thing. Your database design has a critical bug, that prevents querying, indexing or even knowing that your data is valid. You need to fix that bug. Perhaps you tried to use an EAV model without even using type-specific columns. EAV is a *very* bad design that eliminates all advantages of using a relational database without any benefits

Comment: @Larnu yes seems logical, but I am working on a product and I don't think my management will allow me to change the product, what can be the fixes for this?

Comment: If you wanted to store arbitrary fields, you could use sparse columns, XML or JSON fields. Assuming you really need arbitrary fields. More often than not, such designs are "just in case"

Comment: @TWMTV the fixes for *what*? You have no idea what that field contains. You could have avoided storing mixed date *literals* by using `sql_variant` instead of `string`. Right now though, nothing can tell you whether you have `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY-DD-MM` values. Your own query though tries to parse completely different values: `'01-01-2021'`.

Comment: I wouldn't, if I am honest, even suggest `sql_variant`, @PanagiotisKanavos ; using that data type comes with a wealth of caveats and considerations.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes you guys are right I will now just add another column with datetime datatype and will store the particular value in that column, thank you for your help

Comment: @TWMTV in fact, there's absolutely no reason to use `AST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, '01-01-2021', 105), 101) AS DATE) ` and `CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, '31-12-2021', 105), 101) AS DATE)`. You can use just `2021-01-01` or the unseparated format `20210101`. For `date`, both formats are unambiguous. If you want to be doubly cautious you can try `cast('20210101' as date)`

Comment: @TWMTV as for the field, if the field really contains `YYYY-MM-DD` a simple `cast(Ref003 as date)` would be enough. If you want to jump through hoops though, it means the contents don't have the format you assumed.

Comment: @TWMTV long story short, you should be able to write just `WHERE cast(Ref003 as date) between '2020-01-01' and '2021-12-31'`. If that doesn't work, `Ref003` contains inconsistent data. You can use `TRY_CAST` to bypass bad values, but there's no way to guess the format of those bad values. You'll have to inspect and fix the bad data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for the conversion you need to convert to `VARCHAR`, not `DATE`. Note this expression:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(<your date value> AS DATE), 20)
```

With that in mind, you can clean your query up like so:

```
--==== Easily consumable sample data
DECLARE @thetable TABLE (someid INT, thedate DATETIME);
INSERT @thetable
VALUES(1,'2021-04-04 20:01:03'),(2,'2021-06-04 22:01:05'),(1,'2021-04-29 10:31:11');

--==== Solution
SELECT      t.*, FormattedDate = fmt.Dt 
FROM        @thetable                                               AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(t.thedate AS DATE), 20))) AS fmt(Dt)
WHERE       t.thedate BETWEEN '20210401' AND '20210501';
```

**Returns:**

```
someid      thedate                 FormattedDate
----------- ----------------------- -------------
1           2021-04-04 20:01:03.000 2021-04-04
1           2021-04-29 10:31:11.000 2021-04-29
```